# ASP.NET MVC : customization and management of errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to manage errors properly and present the pages I have created to the user. But the problem is that if I get an error from the operations I perform with Ajax on the site, I do not want to redirect to these pages. Because I am returning a JSON message from Catch and displaying this message with a JavaScript library. But the problem is that the page I write to customerros appears anyway and crushes the message I showed with JavaScript. I did it in a complicated way like below. Can anyone with knowledge shed some light?

`global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
        bool isAjaxRequest = Context.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest";

        if (!isAjaxRequest)
        {
            if (exception is HttpException httpException)
            {
                int httpCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();

                if (httpCode == 404)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/Error/NotFound");
                }
                else if (httpCode == 500)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/Error/ServerError");
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/Error/Error");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Error/Error");
            }
        }
}
```

`web.config`:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/Error">
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/NotFound"/>
            <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Error/ServerError"/>
        </customErrors>
```

Error controller:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Error()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult NotFound()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404;
        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ServerError()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 500;
        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        return View();
    }
}
```

```
    Ajax Requests Example
```

```
.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        showToast('Hata', 'İşlem başarıyla gerçekleşti ancak tablo güncellenirken bir sorun oluştu.', false);
    });
```

```
return Json(new { result = true, message = "Müşteri başarıyla eklendi." });
function customerSuccess(response) {
    if (response.result) {
        showToast('Başarılı', response.message, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to handle errors in your ASP.NET application, both for regular requests and for AJAX requests, without redirecting to error pages but rather returning JSON responses for AJAX requests. Your current approach appears to be a mix of both traditional error handling and AJAX error handling. You can simplify this by separating the two concerns more clearly.

For regular requests, you can continue to use the  section in your web.config to handle errors and display error pages. Your existing configuration seems correct for this purpose.

For AJAX requests, you can handle errors and return JSON responses without any redirection. You can use a try-catch block in your AJAX request handlers and return JSON responses with the appropriate error status and messages.

Handle errors in your AJAX requests:

```
  public JsonResult AjaxAction(){
    try
    {
        // Perform some operation that might throw an exception
        // ...

        return Json(new { success = true, message = "Operation successful" });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        return Json(new { success = false, message = "An error occurred: " + ex.Message });
    }
}
```

In this example, if an error occurs during the AJAX operation, you set the HTTP status code to 500 (Internal Server Error) and return a JSON response with the error message. On the client side, you can handle this JSON response and display the error message using JavaScript without any page redirection.

By separating the error handling for regular requests and AJAX requests, you can avoid the need for complex logic in your Application_Error method and simplify your codebase.

Let me know if this works for you ;)

Comment: But I use it differently. I updated my question and gave an example.

Comment: Your current solution seems a bit complex, and there is a more straightforward approach you can consider to handle errors in a more unified way, whether it's for AJAX or non-AJAX requests.

I suggest that you Create a custom error handling filter, 
register it (In your Global.asax.cs you can register the custom error filter globally), 
Use the custom error filter in your controllers (Now, whenever an exception is thrown within a controller action, the CustomErrorFilterAttribute will handle it and return a JSON response for AJAX requests or perform a redirect for non-AJAX requests.)